# NSTextView: When to automatically insert characters (like auto-matching parenthesis)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nstextstorage

I've got an `NSTextView` and I'm acting as its `NSTextStorage` delegate, so I'm getting callbacks for `textStorageWillProcessEditing:` and `textStorageDidProcessEditing:`, and currently I'm using the `did` callback to change some attributes on the text (coloring certain words).

What I'd like to do is add auto-matching of certain character pairs. When the user types `(`, I want to insert a `)` too but I'm not exactly sure when or where is the proper time to do this.

From the text storage delegate protocol, it says the `will` method lets you change the text to be displayed.. but I'm not really sure what that means or how I can do that. The text system is really big and confusing.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In my open-source project, I subclassed `NSTextView` and overrode `insertText:` to handle the insertion of matching characters there. You can examine the argument to `insertText:` to see if it is something you want to act on, call super to perform the normal insertion of text, then call `insertText:` again with the appropriate matching character string if needed.

Something like this:

```
- (void)insertText:(id)insertString {
    [super insertText:insertString];

    // if the insert string isn't one character in length, it cannot be a brace character
    if ([insertString length] != 1)
        return;

    unichar firstCharacter = [insertString characterAtIndex:0];

    switch (firstCharacter) {
        case '(':
            [super insertString:@")"];
            break;
        case '[':
            [super insertString:@"]"];
            break;
        case '{':
            [super insertString:@"}"];
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    // adjust the selected range since we inserted an extra character
    [self setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(self.selectedRange.location - 1, 0)];
}
```